# How to set an image path in src attribute using vue 2

Tags: image, attributes, vue.js, bind, src

İs that possible to give an attribute like that?

```
src="${urlPath}/img/icon-{{flight.OperatingAirline._CompanyShortName}}.png"
```

doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After edit @SLYcee's answer for JSTL combined solution:

```
:src="'${urlPath}/img/icon-' + flight.OperatingAirline._CompanyShortName + '.png'"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `:v-bind` (or shortcut ":") instead of `"{{ }}"` : [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions)

So `:src="Any javascript here !"`

```
:src="urlPath + '/img/icon-' + flight.OperatingAirline._CompanyShortName + '.png'"
```

> `urlPath` and `flight.OperatingAirline._CompanyShortName` must be a javascript variable.

Comment: Thanks @SLYcee and
I made it available with jstl with a little touch:
:src="'${urlPath}/img/icon-' + flight.OperatingAirline._CompanyShortName + '.png'"